# Android Play Games: Custom Room Configuration with flexible amount of players

Tags: android, google-play-services, real-time, google-play-games, multiplayer

I am developing a real time multiplayer game. The game itself is working fine. I am struggling with the Room Configuration. I use google play games as a framework. The game concept is managing an amount of players from 2 up to 7 for a single room. The game is in fashion of a board game. Therefore it is better if many players are connected. Otherwise the game will be boring. I have the possibility to use googles AutoMatchCriteria for a matchmaking:

```
final int MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 6;
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig
    .createAutoMatchCriteria(MIN_OPPONENTS, MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
....
```

If I set MIN_OPPONENTS = 1 and MAX_OPPONENTS = 6 the game will start in most cases with 2 players. In a SO-Thread, a google developer mentioned:

> The automatching algorithm doesn't try very hard to maximize the number of players in the match...

I have the possibility to use MIN_OPPONENTS = 6 and MAX_OPPONENTS = 6 too. With this setup, the game will start only if 7 players are connected to a room. My game provides many game variants and plenty difficulty levels. Therefore I assume that not always 7 players will be available. I need a flexible solution where a game start is always guaranteed.

The same google guy describes a solution using timers: [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802177/4565322)

I do not know where to start with this concept. Where should I start the timer?
Has anyone successfully implemented this concept? It would be very nice if this person can share some code snippet or provide some further explanation with me. **Other suggestions are welcome too.**

**Update 2019: Still looking for a improvement. Pls give hints.**

My gradle file contains:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:6.5.87'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

That's how I start a multiplayer game:

```
    void startQuickGame() {
    final int MAX_OPPONENTS = 6;
    int min_opponents = 1;
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(min_opponents,
            MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setVariant(variant);
    switchToScreen(R.id.mpGamescreen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();

    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());
    }
```

One hint I found here: [Forcefully starting the game after successfully room-creation using Google Play game Service android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693231/forcefully-starting-the-game-after-successfully-room-creation-using-google-play)
They mention some custom timer.

Comment: Do you want it to "try harder" to form larger games, or make it possible to join mid-game?

Comment: I want it to try harder to form larger games.